# Prove that $\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{(n!)^2 2^{2n + 1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that : 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{(n!)^2 2^{2n + 1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Any own thoughts or tries? What have you tried?

Comment: i would say induction

Comment: Observe that $\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n\,dx=2\int_0^1(1-x^2)^n\,dx$, then use a change of variable : $x=\sin(\theta)$. This should lead to a Wallis integral.

Comment: What I try is to use binomial theorem for $(1-x^2)^n$ and then integrate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx\underbrace{=}_{f\text{ even}}2\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^ndx\underbrace{=}_{t=x^2}\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^nt^{-1/2}dt=B(n+1,1/2)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

The trick is induction together with integration by parts. Denote our integral by $I_n$. Then

$$
I_{n+1}=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n(1-x^2)\text{d}x=I_n-\int_{-1}^1 x^2(1-x^2)^n\text{d}x.
$$

Integrating by parts by $u=x$ and $v'=x(1-x^2)^n$ we arrive at the recurrence $$I_{n+1}=\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}I_n.$$

Therefore $$I_{n+1}=\frac{2(n+1)\cdot 2(n+1)(n!)^2\cdot 2^{2n+1}}{2(2n+3)(n+1)(2n+1)!}=\frac{\bigl((n+1)!\bigr)^2\cdot 2^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!},$$ which is the induction step. I leave to you the verification of the formula for $n=1$.